# NSIS: delete AppData folder of logged in user

Tags: windows-10, nsis

I have an installer that have to be executed as an admin. During the installation process the user has the option to execute a clean install. Selected this option the data in the AppData directory should be deleted.
When I am logged in as a non-admin user and the admin enters the credentials I only have access to the AppData directory of the admin. How can delete data in the AppData directory from the actual logged in user?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is of course a consequence of the UAC design.

The official Microsoft recommendation is to just leave behind the junk in %AppData%.

As a workaround you can use [GetUserShellFolderFromRegistry](https://nsis.sourceforge.io/GetUserShellFolderFromRegistry) to get special folders of other users.

If you only want to operate on the SID associated with the current RDP session you can get the SID like this:

```
!include LogicLib.nsh
Function GetThisSessionLogonSidFromLsa
System::Store S
StrCpy $9 ""
System::Call KERNEL32::GetCurrentProcessId()i.s
System::Call KERNEL32::ProcessIdToSessionId(is,*i0r1)i.r0
${If} $0 <> 0
    System::Call 'SECUR32::LsaEnumerateLogonSessions(*i0r2,*p0r3)i.r0'
    ${If} $0 = 0
        IntOp $2 $2 - 1
        ${For} $4 0 $2
            IntOp $5 $4 * 8
            System::Call '*$3(&i$5,l.r5)'
            System::Call 'SECUR32::LsaGetLogonSessionData(*lr5,*p0r5)i.r0'
            ${If} $0 = 0
                System::Call '*$5(p,l,p,p,p,p,p,p,i,i.r6,p.r7)'
                ${If} $6 = $1
                    System::Call 'ADVAPI32::ConvertSidToStringSid(pr7,*p0r8)'
                    System::Call '*$8(&t${NSIS_MAX_STRLEN}.r9)'
                    System::Call 'KERNEL32::LocalFree(pr8)'
                ${EndIf}
                System::Call SECUR32::LsaFreeReturnBuffer(pr5)
            ${EndIf}
        ${IfThen} $9 != "" ${|} ${Break} ${|}
        ${Next}
        System::Call SECUR32::LsaFreeReturnBuffer(pr3)
    ${EndIf}
${EndIf}
Push $9
System::Store L
FunctionEnd

...

Call GetThisSessionLogonSidFromLsa
Pop $0
DetailPrint $0 ; S-1-... (Compare this with the parameter received in the EnumUsersReg callback)
```

For your specific situation, a uglier hack might work:

```
!include LogicLib.nsh
Function GetUsernameOfCurrentSessionFromWTS
Push $0
Push $1
Push $2
StrCpy $2 ""
System::Call 'WTSAPI32::WTSQuerySessionInformation(p0,i-1,i5,*p0r1,*i)i.r0'
${If} $0 <> 0
    System::Call '*$1(&t${NSIS_MAX_STRLEN}.r2)'
    System::Call 'WTSAPI32::WTSFreeMemory(p$1)'
${EndIf}
Exch 2
Pop $1
Pop $0
Exch $2
FunctionEnd

Section
Call GetUsernameOfCurrentSessionFromWTS
Pop $0
RMDir /R "$PROFILE\..\$0\AppData\Roaming\MyApplication"
SectionEnd
```

This assumes that all profiles are stored in `$PROFILE\..` and hardcodes `AppData\Roaming` and neither of those things might be correct in all configurations.

Comment: I know this workaround but there I get the AppData paths for all users. I only need the path for the user who is actually logged in.

Comment: And who is that? The user credentials used on the login screen, the parent process of your installer or the user Explorer.exe is running as? (Could be 3 different users).

Comment: the user credentials used on the login screen